# How can I optimize elementary for slow computers?

Tags: performance

Could anyone provide some tips on how to make elementary OS run faster and use less memory?

Specifically I am running it on a netbook Asus Eee PC 1005HA with an Intel Atom processor (single core) and 2 GB RAM, which I know is fairly limited. The system feels quite slow, especially launching apps. Using Facebook and watching videos on Youtube is also laggy.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to answer this question if we don't know what exactly is running slow. Could you edit the question and describe what's exactly running slow?

Comment: You can always install zram via sudo apt-get install zram-config. It will definitely boost your computer.

Comment: @personinsack `zram` will only help if the computer is paging anything.

Comment: Mind-boggling why the question was closed so quickly. Way to put off new users... There are some general performance tips which could have been worthy answers, which then could be voted by users and OP on how good they work. This would have also made it easier to improve the original question...

Comment: @quassy SE is not good for forum-style questions. We do make exceptions, but it's really not recommended. This question would generate too many possible answers that all say something else, as there is no *one* answer. It would be better if there was a specific problem with a specific cause, which could be targeted with (a) specific answer(s).

Comment: I don't see how this is a forum-style question as there is not a lot of back-and-forth required. The whole idea of SE is to have multiple answers compete for popular vote based on their perceived usefullness. There is not even a chance of him (and others) getting help this way which is absurd considering people are relayed here for support. While not all answers will suit OP some will probably suit others. Especially for graphics it'd be nice to have an answer on how to check drivers are properly running, animations/transparency are disabled, point people to use html5 over flash...

Comment: Yeah good points quassy. So basically I should create different topics for each problem. Like "youtube videos are laggy", "how to make Facebook faster" and etc. Maybe I should just create new topic for every website? I would say it's specific enough I need performance tweaks it can be any tweak since its slow netbook starting from the ones that load cpu and finishing where graphic card ends. The post which suggests most tweaks gets best answer label. Easy.

Comment: as I stated earlier install zram, it should help

Comment: Well and thank you for that. Dunno if it helped maybe a little bit. I enabled that "tweaks" thingy in settings made a high contrast windows and it did helped but it still feels sluggish so it must because of that veryz very pretty interface. :l

Comment: For facebook I created a chrome webapp with m.facebook.com (the mobile site) - it uses much less resources and most of the time is good to go (you can load the full page in a browser whenever the mobile web doesn't do the job, which is not very often imho).
For youtube you can try apps like SMtube or minitube - smtube will use normal video player to play the video so it may be better optimised for the job.